# ¿Cómo sumo con numpy enteros a tuplas dentro de una lista manteniendo en el output la misma estructura original?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo la siguiente lista:

```
a = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)],
    [(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

¿Cómo obtengo la suma de (e.g. +4) a cada valor de la tupla?
Resultado esperado:

```
a = [[(5, 6), (7, 8)],
    [(5, 7), (6, 8)]
```

He hecho lo siguiente con numpy, pero no sé si es la manera más eficiente:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(1,2), (3,4)])
b = np.array([(4,4)])

c = a + b

print c
```

Al obtener c, se obtiene una matriz de datos:

```
>>>[[5 6]
    [7 8]]
```

Me gustaría saber cómo se obtiene la misma estructura original (tuplas dentro de una lista) utilizando numpy. También deseo saber cuál es la manera más eficiente para realizar este tipo de operación.

Comment: Hola Pyring. Qué es lo que has intentado? Por favor, primero investiga e intenta y con los fallos o problemas que tengas, preguntar aquí. Un saludo

Comment: Perdona es verdad, me he adelantado un poco con esta pregunta, que no tiene mucho misterio. La idea era hacerlo de la manera más eficiente posible mediante el uso de numpy

Comment: He añadido lo que sé hacer y hago para conseguir lo que propongo, preguntando si es lo más eficiente. Sobre todo para despejar esas dudas de que busque que alguien me haga trabajo gratis. Un saludo.

Comment: Con numpy, por otra parte, lo que veo es que de la suma no obtengo directamente las tuplas dentro de la lista (como si lo hiciera sin numpy), sino una matriz de datos... imagino que habrá otra manera de hacer lo mismo con numpy (lo que no sé es si más eficientemente). Gracias en cualquier caso por los comentarios. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto también mantendría la estructura interna de tu lista de tuplas, las operaciones `map()` son frecuentemente usadas por su eficiencia.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(1,2), (3,4)])
b = np.array([(4,4)])

list(map(tuple,np.add(a,b)))
Out[1]:[(5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Otra alternativa sería uso de map, funcion lambda y compresion de listas:

```
[tuple(map(lambda x:x+4,i)) for i in a]
Out[1]:[(5, 6), (7, 8)]

# granularizando te explico:
# [ i for i in a] recorre cada tupla de la lista
# map aplica a cada elemento de i(el vector) una funcion
# tuple convierte la lista en tupla
# lambda x:x+4  es una funcion que suma 4 a un numero
```

EDITO:
Para lista de listas, añado una variante que podría ser de utilidad:

```
a = np.array([[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)], [(1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 7), (6, 8)]]) 
b = np.array([(4,4)])

fun = lambda x,y: list(map(tuple,np.add(x,y).tolist()))

[fun(i,b) for i in a]

Out[1]:
[[(5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10), (11, 12)], [(5, 7), (6, 8), (9, 11), (10, 12)]]
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta. He estado haciendo pruebas. Cundo utilizo arrays más largos, obtengo un error: "ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted". Por ejemplo cuando declaro a = np.array([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)], [(1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 7), (6, 8)])

Comment: para el ejemplo que ponías al principio y el de este comentario hay error de escritura o codigo, sería asi: a = np.array([[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)], [(1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 7), (6, 8)]]) , es una lista de listas. Modifico la respuesta para contemplar mas variaciones.

Comment: muchas gracias por el tiempo tomado y tus respuestas, que me han hecho aprender mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que tu pregunta se resuelve con lo que se conoce como [array estructurado](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html), de esta forma los array tendrán la estructura que quieras darle:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(1,2), (3,4)])
b = np.array([(4,4)])

c = a + b
```

Ahora podemos convertir `c` a un array estructurado tal como lo queremos, por ejemplo una tupla de enteros, usando la función [`np.core.records.fromarrays`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromarrays.html#numpy-core-records-fromarrays) que convierte un array plano en uno estructurado y [`transpose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html#numpy-transpose) para rotar el array.

```
c = np.core.records.fromarrays(c.transpose(), 
                                   names='col1, col2',
                                   formats = 'i4, i4')

print(c)
```

La salida:

```
[(5, 6) (7, 8)]
```

Nuestro array `c` ahora es del tipo estructurado, tiene 2 "registros" y 2 columnas llamadas `col1` y `col2`, y los datos son del tipo `int4`. Podremos hacer algunas cosas interesantes:

```
print c[1].col1      # Acceder por nombre a una "celda"
print c["A"]         # Acceder a toda una columna
print c.col1         # También de esta forma
print c[1]           # Acceder a un registro
print c.dtype.fields # Obtener la estructura
print c.dtype.names  # o los nombres de cada columna
```

Los arrays estructurados, también llamados registros, tienen varias ventajas pero no son muy cómodos para toda la matemática que se puede aplicar a un array común (Por ej, el `c = a + b` no funciona), lo habitual sería trabajar con array comunes y dejar los estructurados para necesidades específicas o para visualización.